# Iterate a custom ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, for-loop, android-listview, simpleadapter

I'm trying to create a custom ListView that displays the event's name, date, and the time it starts.

I am able to create the ListView, however only the event's name is displayed. I've tried several experiments with the list adapter and making seperate ArrayLists for each item and that did not work. Can you show me how to get the data in the for loop in the `displaylist()` method to print out the "Event Date" and "Event Time"? The tutorial I'm following hard codes all the data which is not practical. Please follow this link for images of my app and what I hope to display (located at bottom of page): [see images](http://leobee.com/android/push/so/listview.html)

```
public class DataView extends ListActivity{

    FileInputStream inputStream;
    String s = "";
    List<String> eventNames;
    List<String>eventDate;
    List<String>eventStart;
    List<String>eventEnd;
    List<String>eventLocation;
    List<String>eventDelete;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle pop) {

        super.onCreate(pop);

        setContentView(R.layout.columns);
        eventNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        eventDate = new ArrayList<String>();
        eventStart = new ArrayList<String>();
        eventEnd = new ArrayList<String>();
        eventLocation = new ArrayList<String>();
        eventDelete = new ArrayList<String>();


        File myFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Test.txt");

        DownloadFileAsync FileTask = new DownloadFileAsync();

        FileTask.execute(myFile);

    }// end of onCreate



    private class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<File, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(File... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File myFile = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+ "/Schedule.txt");

            while(!myFile.exists()){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }


            File myDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath());
            BufferedReader br = null;
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myDir + "/Schedule.txt"));

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                s = br.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            String result = s;
            return result;
        }// end of do in background


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            JSONArray jsonArray;
            try {
                jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String eventname =jsonObject.getString("event_name");
                    String eventdate =jsonObject.getString("event_date");
                    String eventstart =jsonObject.getString("event_start");
                    String eventend =jsonObject.getString("event_end");
                    String eventlocation =jsonObject.getString("event_location");
                    String eventdelete =jsonObject.getString("event_delete_flag");

                    Log.v("event web address", eventname+ " "+ eventdate+ " "+eventstart+ " "+eventend+ " "+eventlocation+ " "+eventdelete);
                    eventNames.add(eventname);
                    eventDate.add(eventdate);
                    eventStart.add(eventstart);
                    eventEnd.add(eventend);
                    eventLocation.add(eventlocation);
                    eventDelete.add(eventdelete);


                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String[] EventName = new String[ eventNames.size()];
            eventNames.toArray(EventName);

            String[] EventDate = new String[ eventDate.size()];
            eventDate.toArray( EventDate );

            String[] EventStart = new String[ eventStart.size()];
            eventStart.toArray(EventStart);

            String[] EventEnd = new String[ eventEnd.size()];
            eventEnd.toArray( EventEnd);

            String[] EventLocation = new String[ eventLocation.size()];
            eventLocation.toArray(EventLocation);

            String[] EventDelete = new String[ eventDelete.size()];
            eventDelete.toArray( EventDelete);

            displaylist(EventName,EventDate,EventStart,EventEnd,EventLocation, EventDelete);


        }// end of onPostExecute


    }/// end of  DownloadFileAsync
    public void displaylist(String[] EventName, String[] EventDate, String[] EventStart, String[] EventEnd, String[] EventLocation, String[] EventDelete){




        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        int x=(int)EventName.length;
        for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            //initialize row data
            for(int j=0; j<1; j++)
            {
                map.put("Event Name", EventName[i]);
                map.put("Event Date", EventDate[i]);
                map.put("Event Time", EventStart[i]);

            }
            mylistData.add(map);
        }

        SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylistData, R.layout.mylistrow,new String []{"Event Name", "Event Date","Event Time"} , new int[]{R.id.text1,R.id.text2,R.id.text3});
        setListAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
        String event = o.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen event: " + " " + event, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:background="#000fff"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFff00"
        android:text="No data" />

</LinearLayout>
```

mylistrow.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:paddingTop="4dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#FFFF00"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:typeface="sans" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-json-parsing-tutorial.html

Comment: @SamirMangroliya Thanks! This example is a big help.

Comment: I remember reading this and think it may help you. http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92